# Display image in Leaflet (Cloudmade) popups

Tags: leaflet

I am using the default settings for the Leaflet (cloudmade) Simple project (https://github.com/perrygeo/leaflet-simple-csv/blob/master/README.md).

I have a 1300 record CSV which displays well, and on-click the attributes display text in popup window.

Two of the fields are URLs to small JPG images. I would like these to display in the popup window. I've tried  but to no avail.

Link to project: http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/datademo/projects/

How can I show the images?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `<img></img>` tags instead of `<a href></a>`? they are links because they are written as links. Or you can do `<a href="myUrl"><img src="mySource"></a>` dont forget to play with the styling of the img tag. The height and width.

Comment: Yes, I currently have: <img src="img/test.jpg" height="42" width="42"/>  and have hardwire the url as well <img src="http://mysite/img/test.jpg" height="42" width="42"/>   I only get the broken image icon in the popup box.